# Show certain list based on function argument in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to show and hide certain lists based on the function argument passed, is there a way to use jquery show() and hide() to achieve this? Currently if a add a show() to the function I am getting an error "show() is not a function". How do I add show / hide to function parameter or is this not possible as I am doing?

codepen: https://codepen.io/mDDDD/pen/WNwrMLW

```js
$('.additional-questions').hide();
    
        $('.show-list').click(function () {
            $('.additional-questions').show();
          
          additionalQuestionToShow([0]).show().siblings().hide();
        });
    
        function additionalQuestionToShow($element) {
          
          var list = $('.additional-questions-list');
          for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            var listToShow = list[$element];
    
            console.log(listToShow);
          }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="additional-questions">
    
                    <div class="question-row">
                      <p class="text--bold">
                        Additional questions.
                      </p>
                    </div>
    
                    <!-- List 1 -->
                    <ul class="additional-questions-list">
                      <li>
          LIST ONE
                      </li>
                      <li>
           Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                      </li>
                      <li>
                       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                      </li>
                    </ul>
    
                    <!-- List 2 -->
                    <ul class="additional-questions-list">
                      <li>
    LIST TWO
                      </li>
                      <li>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                      </li>
                      <li>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                      </li>
                      <li>
                      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                      </li>
                    </ul>
    
                    <!-- List 3 -->
                    <ul class="additional-questions-list">
                      <li>
    LIST THREE
                      </li>
                      <li>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                      </li>
                      <li>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                      </li>
                      <li>
                 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                      </li>
                    </ul>
    
                  </div><!-- /.additional-questions -->
    
    
    <button class ="show-list">SHOW LIST</button>
```

Comment: There is no error showing in the code you posted?

Comment: @FluffyKitten updated codepen with what I am trying to achieve, thanks :)

Comment: Can you also update the code in the question too, please? Questions here are supposed to be self-contained and include all the information required. External links are ok but only when the code is also in the question, because external links can change or break over time, making the question unhelpful for users in future :) UPDATE: Also, the codepen seems to be the same as this code anyway?

Comment: @FluffyKitten good call and updated...thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing an index, you can use jquery's `eq` to use that number to grab the elements matching the selector in that index. The index is zero based so instead of starting at 1 they start at 0.

I also added some code for showing/hiding elements before and after of the clicking to show list.

```js
$('.additional-questions-list').hide();
$('.question-row').hide();

$('.show-list-1').click(function() {
  $('.additional-questions-list').hide();
  additionalQuestionToShow(0);
});

$('.show-list-2').click(function() {
  $('.additional-questions-list').hide();
  additionalQuestionToShow(1);
});

$('.show-list-3').click(function() {
  $('.additional-questions-list').hide();
  additionalQuestionToShow(2);
});

function additionalQuestionToShow($element) {
  $('.question-row').show();
  $('.additional-questions-list').eq($element).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="additional-questions">

  <div class="question-row">
    <p class="text--bold">
      Additional questions.
    </p>
  </div>

  <!-- List 1 -->
  <ul class="additional-questions-list">
    <li>
      LIST ONE
    </li>
    <li>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </li>
    <li>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </li>
    <li>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- List 2 -->
  <ul class="additional-questions-list">
    <li>
      LIST TWO
    </li>
    <li>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </li>
    <li>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </li>
    <li>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- List 3 -->
  <ul class="additional-questions-list">
    <li>
      LIST THREE
    </li>
    <li>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </li>
    <li>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </li>
    <li>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
<!-- /.additional-questions -->


<button class="show-list-1">SHOW LIST 1</button>
<button class="show-list-2">SHOW LIST 2</button>
<button class="show-list-3">SHOW LIST 3</button>
```